# How to load a component dynamically into a container in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js, components, ember-components

I have a container component

```
{{container}}
```

Whose .hbs (template) file has a

```
<div id='box'></div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

When the **button** is clicked I would like another **component** (say {{image}} to be loaded into it.

Is this possible?

Comment: hmmm - thanks. it might work for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. its possible using `component` helper. [Reference](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component)

For your use case, you can simply say,  `{{#if showImage}} {{image-component }} {{/if}}` and 
toggle `showImage` property upon clicking button

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the "component" helper did it. Absolutely beautiful framework!